# Relation between parameters when their functions are equal

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

We have two expressions:

```
f[x_,t_]:= Sin[1/2 t (1 + x)]^2;
g[x_, t_] := 1/2 Sqrt[Sin[t (1 + x)]]^2;
```

We wish to access a relation between `x` and `t`, where above functions are equal. 
We have tried with:

```
Solve[f[x,t]-g[x,t]==0,x] (*for g[x,t]=>0 *) (Solve[f[x,t]-Abs@g[x,t]==0,x] )
```

But it gives ambiguous answers.

Comment: How about `Reduce[f[x, t] - g[x, t] == 0, {x, t}]`? Is that more like what you're after?

Comment: It is very good comment!!!!!